# Refresh Navigation Bar background color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar with the same color as the view's background.
If the user presses a button, the color of the view is changing, but the color of the nav bar isn't.
If I'm trying to change it manually, with

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 104.0/255.0, green: 154.0/255.0, blue: 26.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

It does changes the navbar background color, but it's not exactly the same as the view's color, even I set the same values for the background.

How can I set the nav bar's color to be the same as the view's color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your navigation bar and in ViewController is because the navigation bar is translucent, the system will apply a default alpha value for the navigation bar.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 104.0/255.0, green: 154.0/255.0, blue: 26.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Or Manually :

Difference in navigation bar and ViewController background colour is 20. which gives UINavigationBar it's built-in styling by giving this a "glossy" look.

So R=104 | G=154 | B=26 will become R=84 | G=134 B| B=6.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 84.0/255.0, green: 134.0/255.0, blue: 6.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 104.0/255.0, green: 154.0/255.0, blue: 26.0/255.0, alpha: 26.0)
```

Comment: I would strongly advise against trying to manually match the color of navigation bar if you need exact matching. The value you suggested is quite different from view's background color. You will never be absolutely able to match the color, for example you can never get fully red, green or blue since navigation bar will always adjust the color to be slightly brighter, and when the user scrolls the content beneath it, it will just change navigation bar's color as it is translucent.

Comment: @frin It’s just a suggestion. Making translucent is a best way. Any other way all to match background color to nav bar color will not give you a exact match. Manually matching color is a optional.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways:

1) Set navigation bar as non-translucent:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

2) Set background image for navigation bar:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "red"), for: .default)
```

You can also provide a generated UIImage based on UIColor with a function like this:

```
func convertUIColorToUIImage(_ color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```